# Ruby and CSV - How to get a column value after filtering rows

Tags: ruby, csv

I have parsed a CSV file with headers of ID, Name, and Address. I need to find the row(s) in the data that have a particular ID and Name. Once I find that row, I need to access the Address value.

```
data = CSV.parse(my_csv, headers: true)

rows = data.select { |row| row['ID'] == someId } //ids are not unique
row = rows.select { |row| row['Name'] == name } //names are unique
```

How do I get the `Address` value in this row of data? `row[2]` doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean `row[2]` doesn't work? What happens? Do you get an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: no error, just an empty value

Comment: What do you mean "an empty value"? Do you mean `nil` or `{}` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to find the row(s) in the data that have a particular ID and Name.

You can combine as many criteria as you wish in a single `select()`:

```
rows = data.select {|row| row['ID'] == someId && row['Name'] == name}
```

In fact, you can make this boolean statement as simple or as complex as you wish. You will need to determine the exact boolean logic necessary to get the results you want.

> I need to access the Address value.

To get the `'Address'` column of each row selected, use `map()`:

```
addresses = rows.map {|row| row['Address']}
```

To get the `'Address'` column of the first row selected:

```
rows[0]['Address']
```

Be careful with this last one, though. It will cause an error if `rows` is empty.

Comment: ok, but that doesn't answer the question - how do I get the `Address` value of that row?

Comment: @soleil added in my latest edit

Answer (score 1):

Let's first create some test data.

```
my_csv = <<~_
ID,Name,Address
1,cat,Mars
2,dog,Jupyter
1,dog,Venus
_
  #=> "ID,Name,Address\n1,cat,Mars\n2,dog,Jupyter\n1,dog,Venus\n"
```

```
puts my_csv
ID,Name,Address
1,cat,Mars
2,dog,Jupyter
1,dog,Venus
```

---

As it is guaranteed that the values of `'Names'` are unique, we can use [Enumerable#find](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find), which terminates as soon as the condition in its block evaluates `true`.

```
require 'csv'

def find_addr(csv_str, id, name)
  row = CSV.parse(csv_str, headers: true).find do |row|
    row['ID'] == id && row['Name'] == name
  end
  row.nil? ? nil : row['Address']
end
```

```
find_addr(my_csv, "1", "cat") #=> "Mars"
find_addr(my_csv, "1", "dog") #=> "Venus"
find_addr(my_csv, "2", "dog") #=> "Jupyter"
find_addr(my_csv, "2", "pig") #=> nil
```

Note that `row` is assigned `nil` if no row satisfies the block condition.

---

We could shorten this by using the [Safe Navigation Operator](https://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/), `&`.

```
def find_addr(csv_str, id, name)
  CSV.parse(csv_str, headers: true).find do |row|
    row['ID'] == id && row['Name'] == name
  end&.[]('Address')
end
```

```
find_addr(my_csv, "1", "cat") #=> "Mars"
find_addr(my_csv, "1", "dog") #=> "Venus"
find_addr(my_csv, "2", "dog") #=> "Jupyter"
find_addr(my_csv, "2", "pig") #=> nil
```

Note that when using the Safe Navigation Operator we cannot use *syntactic sugar* versions of methods, here

```
...end&['Address']
```

would raise an exception.

---

If `find_addr` returning `nil` signals that there is a problem with the data we could either handle that in code or remove the Safe Navigation Operator in the second method above, which would cause a `NoMethodError` exception to be raised if no row satisfies the required condition.